# Why is the method #each_index non existing for hashes in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, hashmap

Why can I use #each and #each_with_index on both arrays and hashes, but the #each_index method can be used only on an array and not on a hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> each_index
>
> Iterates over array indexes.

Hashes don't have indexes. Hashes have keys. Use [`each_key`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-each_key).

Why do Hashes have `each_with_index`? Because that's part of the Enumerable module which both Hashes and Arrays include. Enumerable methods use shared terminology. Hashes and Arrays predate the Enumerable module, Array#each_index (sometime before v1.0r2) came before Enumerable#each_with_index (Feb 5th, 1998), so there is some overlap between Array, Hash, and Enumerable for backwards compatibility.

Comment: so the #each_index method is not defined inside of the Enumerable module, but just on the Array class?

Comment: Lorenzo, why are you asking when you can check that yourself? See [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html).

Comment: Checking that list of methods on the left I don't see #each, why is that?

Comment: @LorenzoZabot `each` must be implemented by the class including Enumerable. `each` is what makes something able to be enumerated. https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#module-Enumerable-label-Usage

Answer (score 0):

Hashes don't have indexes. The order of elements in a Hash is unstable and can change. You can iterate over keys and values with `each`.

```rb
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
hash.each do |key, val|
 puts "#{key.inspect} => #{val.inspect}"
end

#=> :a => 1
#=> :b => 2
```

If you really need to iterate over a hash with a counter of some sort you can just chain `each` with `with_index` like so:

```rb
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
hash.each.with_index do |key_val, i|
 key, val = key_val
 puts "#{i}| #{key.inspect} => #{val.inspect}"
end

#=> 0| :a => 1
#=> 1| :b => 2
```